# ¿Como pasar a PHP 7 esta clase y funcion?

Tags: php

he estado migrando de PHP 5 a 7 el código de mi proyecto, ya que mysql no corre en el servidor en cambio mysqli si, pero tengo una clase y función que no he logrado hacer que funcione ya que con la versión anterior de PHP si funcionaba, el código es el siguiente.

```
class Consultar_Grado{
    private $consulta;
    private $fetch;

    function __construct($codigo){
        $this->consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM grado WHERE id=$codigo");
        $this->fetch = mysql_fetch_array($this->consulta);
    }

    function consultar($campo){
        return $this->fetch[$campo];
    }
}
```

Ya que al cambiar las sentencias a mysqli o intentar con otros métodos siempre manda errores, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: ¿Esta clase como obtiene la conexión de mysql?

Comment: cual es el error exacto que te da

Comment: Debes mostrar también el código donde se crea la conexión, el cual debe ser migrado también, de lo contrario no funcionará.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente codigo:

```
class Consultar_Grado{
private $consulta;
private $fetch;

function __construct($codigo){
    $this->consulta = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM grado WHERE id='".$codigo."'");
    $this->fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($this->consulta);
}

function consultar($query){
    return $this->mysqli_stmt_fetch[$query];
}
}
```

No lo he testeado pero en teoría asi debería funcionar